# Web date picker: Getting @html helper in MVC to set input type as 'date' rather than 'datetime'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I am writing an MVC application in ASP.NET and dutifully using the @html helpers to produce form elements. However, I cannot find a way to get the helper to set the `type` attribute on the `input` element to `date` (which gives me a convenient date picker) rather than than `datetime` (reflecting the C# data type).

The helper code is:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

(`StartDate` has type `DateTime`)

This generates HTML:

```
<input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Start Date must be a date." data-val-required="The Start Date field is required." id="StartDate" name="StartDate" type="datetime" value="21/10/2021">
```

Now if I replace the helper code with this in my cshtml file and change `type=datetime` to `type=date`, everything renders beautifully and I get a handy date picker. Of course, behind the scenes this is an ugly hack and I would like a more elegant way of doing things.

I have seen a lot of articles talking about getting a date picker via jQuery but this seems to be a bit overkill since HTML does this for you intrinsically.

Can anyone offer some advice?

Comment: You already have `@class = "form-control"` as an attribute, does adding `, @type = "date"` override it? By the way, that `value` won't work; it has to be in `yyyy-MM-dd` format for `type="date"` to pick it up.

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks - works a treat!

Comment: Have you tried decorating your `StartDate` property with `[DataType(DataType.Date)]`?